Encrypted LUKS fs inside a file: sparse or not?
I have a LUKS encrypted file filled with around 160 GB of data
that I use a lot. For safety, I created the file with 400 GB. 
That is, of course, a lot of wasted space. 
So I switched to a sparse file, basically following the advice here,
simply by creating the file with the seek option:

dd if=/dev/zero of=<file> bs=1G count=0 seek=400

But then I thought: what happens if the file begins to be fragmented? 
Usually this is not a problem since I don't have very big files,
and when I do, they are media files that usually don't change. 
But an encrypted thing that I use so frequently
will probably get fragmented quite soon...
So my question is: is there any true downside to using a sparse file instead of a fixed-sized file in my situation? 
Is fragmenting really an issue? Do you have any further advice?

How did you create the LUKS volume in the sparse file?

Sorry, the link was deleted. I followed the instructions here: https://serverfault.com/a/742664 Essentially it's the "standard" process with dd and criptsetup, except for the dd thing, where you fill with zeros instead of \dev\random, and  count=0 seek=size (full command in the original thread).

In theory fragmentation can become an issue, as you have two layers of fragmentation now – both the inner and outer filesystems – but practically speaking, if it's stored on an SSD you probably won't notice it at all (as there is no seek latency).
LUKS encryption is 1:1 and has no effect in either direction.
If you feel any performance issues in the future, you can always use fallocate to request the OS to fully allocate a currently-sparse file, then defragment it using e4defrag (or whatever is appropriate for the underlying filesystem).
And vice versa, you can fstrim a loop-mounted filesystem to make its underlying file sparse again – as well as to re-trim it after deleting large files. (This needs 'allow discard' to be enabled at LUKS layer.)

Please allow me to ask you several questions about your answer (sorry!!!): 1. Everything I have is in NVMEs, so I guess it is as SSDs in this regard. Right? 2. Aren't chances of corruption bigger with sparse files? 3. e4defrag should be run over the encrypted unmounted file, right? 4. Should I also defragment the mounted encrypted FS? 5. Indeed I have seen write speed improvements after e4defrag with normal (non-sparse) encrypted files. Does this make sense?


Well... yes, but "NVME" is not a device, it's a disk communications protocol. There are SATA disks (HDDs or SSDs) and there are NVMe disks (mostly SSDs). An SSD is an SSD, no matter if it talks SATA or NVMe, or if it's 2.5" shaped or M.2 shaped. It's possible that NVMe SSDs will be even less affected by fragmentation than SATA SSDs, but both kinds are much less affected than mechanical HDDs.



Not by much; the underlying filesystems take care of keeping metadata consistent when regular files grow or fragment, for example, and it's the same for sparse files.



Yes, sorry, I always forget. I meant SSD NVMe M.2.



Yes, on the sparse file that's being discussed. 4. Same as for the external file – frequently-modified files might need defragmentation, but probably doesn't matter on an SSD.

